# A seemingly naive question on continuous functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity, soft-question

This question was motivated by the argument in [Possible progress on the Riemann hypothesis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3349386/409686) where the Riemann hypothesis is purportedly proved.

The crux of the OP's argument claiming to prove the RH is that, **IF $F, G$ are continuous functions and $F(s)=G(s)$ for all $s>a$, then BOTH $F(s), G(s)$ must behave similarly as $s\rightarrow a^+$ ?**

It seems to me the above should be obviously true, but since other OP's strongly disagreed on that post, can someone explain why the above is not necessarily true, if at all it is false ?

Note that though the motivation is the linked post, the present is a genuine question on something that i thought should be obviously true. So this post has really nothing to do with the linked one claiming to prove the RH.

**EDIT 1:** By ''behave similarly'', i mean if $F(s)$ converges/diverges as $s\rightarrow a^+$, then so must $G(s)$.

For example, let $F(s)=\prod_{p}(1-p^{-s})^{-1}$ denote the Euler product over primes $p$. Then we have $F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}$ for **ALL** $s>1$. Since the sum $1+1/2 + 1/3 + \cdots$ diverges, it follows that $F(s)$ must also diverge as $s\rightarrow 1^+$, and this way one can deduce the infinitude of primes.

**EDIT 2:** Could the downvotes be explained please ?? Because this post clearly doesn't violate any MSE rule(s). Moderators intervene please.

Comment: No, the crux of that argument is not what you say - translating to this context the claim there is that $F$ and $G$ "behave similarly" _in a neighborhood of $a$_. That's much stronger than "as $s\to a^+$".

Comment: One needs something more than continuity to justify a "behave similarly" conclusion.  A precise definition of that notion *might* shed light on possible counterexamples.

Comment: @userTheta. (who is probably also the OP in the previous question): it feels to me that you don't really understand what other users point out to you. It also seems that you do not listen to their arguments, before dismissing them.

Comment: You said that @reuns' comment in the original question was ''irrelevant''. So yes, you did dismiss it without trying to understand his post first.

Comment: @Klangen, yes reuns' comment was indeed irrelevant for my argument. Reuns was agreeing with punctured dusk who thought that i deduced something like ''$F(s)$ converges at $s=a$ if it converges at $s>a$'', which is clearly not what i said (as you can check). To be fair, it is actually them who commented before understanding my argument.

Comment: @userTheta. So you continue dismissing his example. I don't understand what you want from us: you come here, tell us that we're all wrong, then ask us where your argument fails. And so on, and so on.

Comment: To clarify, to dispose of your "obviously true" claim by reasoned mathematical argument, one needs definitions of various phrases used.  For example, where is it that $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are continuous?  One doesn't simply say functions are continuous without defining their domains.  We also need a definition of "behave similarly" as mentioned before.  By omitting those definitions you give Readers the impression that your Question is adopting definitions of the early Question, even if you are asking about a different conclusion.

Comment: @Klangen, to be fair (again), the same can also be said about Conrad's answer. What Conrad wrote is correct but irrelevant for my argument, which has absolutely nothing to do with Landau's theorem that he quoted, not to mention some of the things mentioned in that answer. It's unfortunate that both of those answers were heavily upvoted despite being irrelevant as i clearly explained below those answers and the objective reader can check for themselves. Surely, mathematics should not be like politics where the ''vote of the majority'' carries the day.

Comment: @hardmath, i first derived that the domain of the relevant equation on the real axis is $s\geq \Theta$. Thus the continuity was for $s\geq \Theta$. ''Behave similarly'' in this case is more about convergence (or lack thereof). By the way, thanks-at least I'm finally discussing mathematics.

Comment: Please edit the body of your Question to pose the problem in a reasonably self-contained way.  If your concern is "about convergence", state what is to be shown in a rigorous way.  Your familiarity with thoughts about the earlier Question does not help Readers to respond here in a cogent way, though of course it is understandable that you are motivated by thoughts provoked there.

Comment: The thesis in bold seems like it should be true to me too, although as someone has pointed out one would need to define exactly what's meant by *behave similarly* -- does that merely mean they converge to the same limit at $a+,$ or some stronger claim? To definitely say, and perhaps begin to consider rigorous justification, one would have to define the phrase *behave similarly* properly.

Comment: You are not providing a problem statement here.  If you have a problem you want help with, give a self-contained problem statement.  What is the setup (assumptions and definitions)?  What is the goal (a proof of a claim or other disposition)?  You say you have a Question that is independent of the previous one, but you refer back to it every time you turn around, which leads me to suspect you have not separated out a new Question yet.

Comment: @hardmath, it seems we are now diverting from what I'm asking here. Hence you can forget my first question on the claimed proof of the RH, and simply consider the present question in its edited form. Indeed, this current question is independent of the first, though it was motivated by it. So let's exclusively focus on the present question, to avoid referring to the first.

Comment: Framing challenge:  The referenced prior Question has "**thus both sides of** (1) **must exhibit similar behavior in the neighborhood of** $s=\Theta$."  Ignoring that there is no equation labelled "(1)" or called out to be referred to as "(1)", this is a substantially different claim than the one in the instant Question  about a limit on the right half of that neighborhood.  This Question asserts, but fails, to address the claim of the prior Question.

Comment: "Could the downvotes be explained please ? Because this post clearly does not violate any MSE rule(s)." A downvote doesn't mean the post has violated any rules. It simply means the voter has found the question unclear or not useful. Voters on this site are not obligated to explain their votes, up or down. "Moderators intervene please." That won't get any moderator's attention – the way to do that is to flag the question and ask for moderator attention. But users can vote as they please, and no moderator will do anything about it.

Comment: I have deleted several comments on this post. Please stay on topic and **be nice**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interpretation of the question in current form, and something lifted from the comments...

> If $F,G$ are continuous functions defined on some common open neighbourhood $U=(a,a+C)\subset \mathbb R$ and $F(s) = G(s)$ for all $s>a$, $s\in U$, [...]
>    if $F(s)$ converges or diverges as $s\to a^+$, then so must $G(s)$.

Yes. Afterall, 
the definition of the limit as $s\to a^+$ depends only on the values of the function on a right neighbourhood of $a$.

> AFTER establishing that the domain of the relevant equation on the real axis includes all 
>   $s
> ≥
> Θ$
>   , which allows one to investigate what happens as 
>   $s
> →
> (
> Θ
> −
> \epsilon
> )
> ^+$
>   .

No.  Maybe try substituting  actual numbers into your argument. Say that a Big Man in The Sky told you that $\Theta=0$. (For instance, you could be studying the function $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-s)^n$ and you're delighted to find out that its equal to $\frac{1}{s}$ for every $2>s>0$.)

Now you want to study a limit as $s\to -\epsilon^+$. Maybe $\epsilon=\frac1{100}$. Maybe smaller, it doesn't matter.  I invite you to notice that (and if you got this far, you already agreed) the definition of a limit as $s\to (-\frac{1}{100})^+$, depends on the values of the function on a right neighbourhood of $-\frac{1}{100}$. And there is an entire open interval $(-1/100,0)$ between $-1/100$ and $0$...

Comment: Thanks @Calvin Khor !